# Find TOP 3 of two columns match

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hiveql

This is the below data in my Table1

```
BID           PID                       TIME
---------+-------------------+----------------------
1345653       330760137950       2012-07-09 21:42:29
1345653       330760137950       2012-07-09 21:43:29
1345653       330760137950       2012-07-09 21:40:29
1345653       330760137950       2012-07-09 21:41:29
1345653       110909316904       2012-07-09 21:29:06
1345653       221065796761       2012-07-09 19:31:48
```

So If I need to clarify the above scenario- I have data in above table like this-
For USER `1345653` I have this PID `330760137950` `four times` but with different timestamps. So I need the output something like this-

Output that I need:-

```
1345653       330760137950       2012-07-09 21:43:29
1345653       330760137950       2012-07-09 21:42:29
1345653       330760137950       2012-07-09 21:41:29
1345653       110909316904       2012-07-09 21:29:06
1345653       221065796761       2012-07-09 19:31:48
```

So Basically If `BID` and `PID` are same but with different `timestamps`, then I need TOP 3 of those sorted with TIME in descending order

And for this I created `rank UDF` (User Defined Function) in Hive. And I wrote the below query but its not working for me. Can anyone help me on this?

```
SELECT bid, pid, rank(bid), time, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time)
FROM (
    SELECT bid, pid, time
    FROM table1
    where to_date(from_unixtime(cast(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) as int))) = '2012-07-09'
    DISTRIBUTE BY bid,pid
    SORT BY bid, time desc
) a
WHERE rank(bid) < 3;
```

So with above query I am getting output like this

```
1345653       330760137950       2012-07-09 21:43:29
1345653       330760137950       2012-07-09 21:42:29
1345653       330760137950       2012-07-09 21:41:29
```

which is wrong as I am missing last two rows of the `Expected Output` above. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select bid, pid, [time] from (
    select bid, pid, [time], rank() over (partition by bid, pid order by [time] desc) as k 
    from #temp ) as x 
where k  <=3
order by bid, pid, time desc
```

oh i'm in sql server.  i don't think you are........

anyway.  my recommendation is that you move your rank function inside of the nested select you have.  in the outside select you want it where it is less than three... i don't know your syntax.  i shouldn't have  answered this question.  sorry.... lol

here:
http://ragrawal.wordpress.com/2011/11/18/extract-top-n-records-in-each-group-in-hadoophive/
your rank() is in the outer select... it needs to be in the inner.  leave the < 4 or <= 3 or whatever in the outer where statement, though.  your query almost looks exactly like that example... just needs a few changes.

**based on the link and my absolute LACK of knowledge of Hive...  i think you might want this:**

```
SELECT bid, pid, time
FROM (
    SELECT bid, pid, rank(time) as rank, time
    FROM $compTable 
    DISTRIBUTE BY bid, pid
    SORT BY bid, pid, time desc
) a
WHERE rank < 4
ORDER BY bid, pid, time desc
```

and i can't test or compile because honestly i had no clue what hive was before you posted your question.  (small world, i know, so sad - so true)

Comment: Yeah. I am working in Hive. I am using this query by modifying yours `select buyer_id, item_id, created_time from (
  select buyer_id, item_id, created_time, rank() over (partition by buyer_id, item_id order by created_time desc) as k 
  from testingtable1 ) as x 
 where k  <=3
 order by buyer_id, item_id, created_time desc;` And I am getting error as `FAILED: Parse Error: line 2:52 mismatched input '(' expecting FROM in from clause`. Any suggestions why is it so?

Comment: no.... i dunno.  your code runs in sql server.  it may not like that nested select as the only from "table"..... you might need to stick the nested select in a temp table and then select * from #temp where k <=3 or something...?

Comment: or hive doesn't have rank()... sorry!

Comment: But I have already created rank as a User Defined Function in Hive.

Comment: I am actually folliwng the same tutorial, but still having the same problem. Still not getting the exact output.

Comment: post your new code up there...?  i don't really know anything about hive....  the link says they want the top N categories.  you want the top N values (which is time in your example).  i would assume Hive's distribute is similar to PARTITION for sql/oracle.